# Why are my max and min int not working when I compile my program?

Tags: c, gcc

I don't understand why I am getting the error:

```
~/SecureSoftware$ gcc AddNumTest.c
AddNumTest.c:11:0: warning: "INT_MAX" redefined [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include-fixed/limits.h:121:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
```

I am looking for a way to not crash my program when a big number is added in the command line.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#define INT_MAX  (2147483647)
#define INT_MIN  (-2147483647)

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int i, TotalOfNumbers = 0;


   for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
   {
      TotalOfNumbers += atoi(argv[i]);
      printf("Total of numbers entered = %d\n", TotalOfNumbers);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you defining your own `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN`? As the warning says, they're already provided -- and the provided values are the correct ones for your platform.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Because he is trying to set the range of valid integers, I think...

Comment: Whenever I don't define them I throw this error message. AddNumTest.c:12:0: warning: "INT_MIN" redefined [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include-fixed/limits.h:119:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition

Comment: @Derk, pardon? That error message only happens when something is defined in two places. One of those places would be inside `limits.h` (or something it calls). The other would be when you add the explicit `#define`. The answer is to take out the `#define`s, and let `#include <limits.h>` do its job.

Answer (score 5):

Redefining `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` doesn't change the actual limits, it just makes the constants describing them inaccurate.

The limits are based on your platform's integer sizes / widths. To have genuinely different limits, you need to use different data types (for instance, `long` rather than `int`).

If a `long` isn't big enough, you may need to move up further, to a `long long`; note that these aren't specified prior to the C99 standard, so you need to have a reasonably modern compiler.

---

Changing your program to use `long`s instead of `int`s would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   long long i, TotalOfNumbers = 0;

   for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
   {
      TotalOfNumbers += atoll(argv[i]);
      printf("Total of numbers entered = %lld\n", TotalOfNumbers);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can compile my program now, but when I run an integer the such as "22020202202020" my program will show it returned as "Total of numbers entered = -95124572" I changed my values to longs

Comment: @Derk, works perfectly for me on an x86_64 system (with that specific number; can't go above MAX_LONG, of course).

Comment: @Derk ...that said, I modified it to use `long long`s -- though with a 64-bit compiler, that shouldn't be necessary. If you're able to reproduce a problem, please provide the EXACT integer you used in generating it.

Comment: Okay when I added the long long my program compiles but it does not read out the correct number. This is exactly what I have typed. " ./a.out 22220020202 45
Total of numbers entered = 745183722
Total of numbers entered = 745183767" My program will add the 45 but i have no idea why i am getting the first number?

Comment: You maybe want the `printf` *after* the loop?  I'm not sure where 745183722 is coming from, though, unless maybe your `long long` isn't actually 64 bits.  I wouldn't put that past Microsoft, but your error messages look like GCC, so that isn't it.

Comment: @Derk, was that with the `long` version or the `long long` version?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the *correct* way to convert text to integers in C: unlike `atoi`, `strtol` will actually tell you if the number is too large, although in a somewhat awkward fashion.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

long
reliable_atol(const char *s)
{
    char *endp;
    long rv;
    errno = 0;
    rv = strtol(s, &endp, 10);
    if (errno || endp == s || *endp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "number malformed or out of range: %s\n", s);
        exit(1);
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Use this function instead of `atoi` in your code, and change `TotalOfNumbers` to `long` (and print it with `%ld`).

You might also want to try to detect overflow in the *addition*, but you can do that without using `INT_MAX` or `INT_MIN`:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    long TotalOfNumbers = 0;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        long n = reliable_atol(argv[i]);
        long sum = (long) ((unsigned long)TotalOfNumbers + (unsigned long)n);
        if ((n > 0 && sum < TotalOfNumbers) || (n < 0 && sum > TotalOfNumbers)) {
            fputs("numeric overflow while computing sum\n", stderr);
            exit(2);
        }
        TotalOfNumbers = sum;
    }
    printf("total %ld\n", TotalOfNumbers);
    return 0;
}
```

The casts are required, because signed integer overflow provokes undefined behavior but unsigned integer overflow doesn't.  This code technically won't work on a non-twos-complement CPU but nobody has manufactured one of those in decades and the C standard's continued provision for the possibility is getting decidedly silly.

If I stick the above two code samples together, making a complete program, I get this for your test case:

```
$ gcc -O2 -Wall test.c       # default mode for this CPU+OS: long is 64 bits
$ ./a.out 22220020202 45
total 22220020247

$ gcc -O2 -Wall -m32 test.c  # alternative mode: long is 32 bits
$ ./a.out 22220020202 45 
number malformed or out of range: 22220020202
```

Comment: When I try to detect overflow I throw this error message. "AddNumTest.c: In function ‘main’:
AddNumTest.c:16:2: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
AddNumTest.c:16:2: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code"

Comment: Sorry, that was sloppy of me.  Just take the `int` out of `for (int i = 1; ...`

Comment: Okay, When I try to compile it now I receive this error message " gcc AddNumTest.c
/tmp/cc96bWF7.o: In function `main':
AddNumTest.c:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `reliable_atol'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status"

Comment: You need both code fragments for a complete program.  You don't seem to be even *trying* to understand what the error messages are saying - yes, they are terse and cryptic, but they are meaningful.